# CDF of a mixed type random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $U$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1$]. We define $X$ such that

$$X = U-0.5 \quad \textrm{if} \quad U - 0.5 \geq 0$$
$$X = 0 \quad \textrm{if} \quad U - 0.5 \leq 0.$$

The task is to find the CDF $F_{X}$.

We know that $X \in [0, 0.5]$.

Let $0 \leq c \leq 0.5$. Then,

$$\begin{align}F_{X}(c) =& P(X\leq c)\\
=& P(U-0.5 \leq c)\\
=& P(U \leq c + 0.5)\\
=& \int_{?}^{c+0.5}du
\end{align}$$

Since $U \geq 0.5$, shouldn't the lower limit in the above integral be $0.5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process seems to confuse the definition of $X$ to be always $U-0.5$. I think with some careful consideration for the limits of $c$ this could work, but I would recommend avoiding the issue altogether by breaking the probability into segments.

$$F_X(c)=P(X\leq c)\\
=P(X\leq c \land U-0.5>0)+P(X\leq c \land U-0.5\leq0)\\
=P(U-0.5\leq c \land U-0.5>0)+P(0\leq c \land U-0.5\leq0)\\
=P(U\leq c+0.5 \land U>0.5)+P(U\leq0.5)\\
=\int_{0.5}^{c+0.5}\ du + 0.5\\
=[(c+0.5)-(0.5)]+0.5\\
=c+0.5$$

Note that this assumes $c\geq 0$; if not, then the probability that converts to an integral should instead be $0$, as would the probability of $0\leq c$.